# Turning pages using a parser how can you implement it?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to write a loop so that the parser collects data from all pages, but my version does not work, how could I implement it differently?

```
import time 
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from datetime import datetime


webdriver = r"C:\Users\К.Бояр (Второй)\source\repos\RozetaParcer\chromedriver.exe"

driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?producer=gazer&seller=rozetka&text=Gazer")

total = []
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".goods-tile.ng-star-inserted")
cur_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
for item in items:
    t_name = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__title').text
    t_price = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__price-value').text
    t_nal = item.find_element_by_css_selector('.goods-tile__availability').text    
    row = cur_date, t_name, t_price, t_nal
    total.append(row)

driver.close()
    
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['Date','Name', 'Price', 'Nal'])
df.to_csv(f'Rozetka_parcer_{cur_date}.csv')
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]. You also need to provide the relevant HTML in the question itself. The link is great for full context but the HTML of the page could change tomorrow making this question useless for future readers.

Comment: I have a problem not with debugging, but with a loop, because I cannot write it correctly so that it works, could you help me with this problem? Now I will change the code a little so that you understand the essence of the problem

Comment: You have a problem with debugging... and so do we. You want us to help you but if you were able to debug it successfully, you wouldn't need our help. Since you do need our help, we are going to need details that I asked for in my first comment... the error message, what line the error message appears on, etc. You also need to reduce your code down to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem... an [mcve], which I also asked for in my first comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to get button with `.pagination__direction_type_forward` in a while loop until button get disabled and gray ( this means you are at last page ) on that while loop you get items before you click on the next page button
there to many way to approach this but the easiest imo is this ( and this problems its different for every websites because they are different in tech they used and the html they have )

Comment: Do not consider it arrogant, but could you please write this into the code for me, because the topic for me is new and not a profile one, I do not quite understand what is needed from me

Comment: I would be immensely good for you